# Data variable in jquery ajax function

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-post

I'm trying to use the code below, but it's not working:
UPDATED WORKING:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.infor').click(function () {
     var datasend = $(this).html();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://domain.com/page.php',
            data: 'im_id='+datasend',
            success: function(data){
                $('#test_holder').html(data);
            }
            });
    }); 
});
```

As you can see I used `$datasend` as the var to send but it doesn't return the value of it, only its name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change
    `$datasend = $(this).html;`
to
    `var datasend = $(this).html();`

Next I would change
    `data: 'im_id=$datasend',`
to
    `data: 'im_id='+datasend,`

Comment: How could I pass another variable in the data line? Fox example something like this: `'im_id='+datasend&'ot_id='+data2send`

Comment: All you have to do is concatenate them (if you want to use that route) together.  There are some quote problems with your code block above. `'im_id='+datasend+'&ot_id='+data2send`

In the long run you may want to assign all of this data to an array and then POST the array rather than build a giant string.