# Multiple data variables in jquery ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables, post

Yesterday I had [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023275/data-variable-in-jquery-ajax-function) (answered), which I have to expand a bit more today. I need to pass two or more variables, but I can't find the proper syntax:
UPDATED, WORKING CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $('.infor').click(function () {

    var datasend = $(this).html();
    var datasendmore = $(this).next().html();

      $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'http://domain.com/page.php',
           data: {im_id:datasend, yt_id:datasendmore},
           success: function(data){
              $('#test_holder').html(data);
              }
           });
    }); 
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does .next work in this way or is it .next() that you need?

Comment: Right, updated above the snippet again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
data: {im_id:datasend,yt_id:datasendmore}
```

Comment: That was quick. I updated my question with the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

There is one minor typo:

data: 'im_id='+datasend','

should be

data: 'im_id='+datasend+',

From what I can see above.

and I'd use {im_id: value1, param2:value2, param3:value3 etc}